# Why can't the program pass these assertions?

Tags: java, assert

My code: (class name is math and it implements an interface)

```
public boolean isPrime(int n){
    for (int i=2; i<n; i++){
        if (n%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Assertions needed to pass:

```
assert math.isPrime(2);
assert math.isPrime(3);
assert math.isPrime(53);
assert !math.isPrime(55);
assert !math.isPrime(24);
assert !math.isPrime(-37337);
```

Oddly enough I've found that the method will pass the -37337 assertion by changing my code to:

```
for (int i=2; i<n; i++){

          if (!(n%i==0)){
              return true;
          }

      }
      return false;
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to pass all of the assertions

Comment: Note copied from wikipedia: "A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number **greater than 1** that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers...." - code is not testing for greater than 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it never enters the loop (2 is greater than -37337)